# Solving data race in benchmark function that simulates stream

Tags: go

I'm trying to write a function that basically benchmarks streamed CSV over to a HTTP endpoint.

To do this I want to generate data and POST that data.

However, `go`s data race detector says that there is a data race and the benchmark finishes faster than I would believe is reasonable, so I guess the HTTP request is not properly processed.

How should I structure my test code to avoid this?

Is there a way to wait until the HTTP client call has been processed?

```
func BenchmarkStream(b *testing.B) {
    header := "header\n"
    buf := bytes.NewBufferString(header)

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            buf.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("%d\n", i+1))
        }
        wg.Done()
    }()                 <-- this line is mentioned in the data race detector

    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    r, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "/", buf)
    h := &MyHandler{}
    h.ServeHTTP(w, r)  

    wg.Wait()

    if w.Code != 200 {
        b.Errorf("test failed")
    }
}
```

EDIT: @Grzegorz Żurs comment made me question my approach to begin with, I refactored it with an `io.Pipe`:

```
func BenchmarkStream(b *testing.B) {
    pr, pw := io.Pipe()
    go func() {
        pw.Write([]byte("header\n"))

        for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
            pw.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("%d\n", i+1)))
        }
    }()

    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    r, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", "/", pr)
    h := &MyHandler{}
    h.ServeHTTP(w, r)  

    if w.Code != 200 {
        b.Errorf("test failed")
    }
}
```

Comment: You are benchmarking bytes.Buffer.WriteString, not your handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sharing `buf` between two goroutines.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to get useful benchmark results if you only invoke the handler once. Build the request body once and then invoke your handler over and over again.

```
buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
buf.WriteString("header\n")
buf.WriteString(strings.Repeat("1\n", 1000)
body := buf.Bytes()

b.ResetTimer()

for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    r, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "/", bytes.NewReader(body))
    if err != nil {
        b.Fatal(err)
    }

    h := &MyHandler{}
    h.ServeHTTP(w, r)  

    if w.Code != 200 {
        b.Errorf("test failed")
    }
}
```